# Outlook 2010 oft template Item_Send not firing

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, vba

I have written a very simple `Item_Send` handler for an outlook mail message template stored as an `oft` file that I run via a Macro:

```
Function Item_Send()
    MsgBox "hello"
    Item_Send = False
End Function
```

This event is not firing: I see no message box and the message sends.

Can anyone explain why this would be and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The code fails to work because it is not configured correctly to tie in to the built-in Outlook event-handling system.  The below code and description, copied directly from the "Example" section on this page<sup>1</sup>, provides a template for implementing custom code in response to sending a mail item.

> The following Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) example shows how to cancel the ItemSend event in response to user input. The sample code must be placed in a class module, and the Initialize_handler routine must be called before the event procedure can be called by Outlook.
>
> ```
> Public WithEvents myOlApp As Outlook.Application 
> Public Sub Initialize_handler() 
>
> Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application 
>
> End Sub 
>  
>  
> Private Sub myOlApp_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean) 
> Dim prompt As String 
>
> prompt = "Are you sure you want to send " & Item.Subject & "?" 
>
> If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sample") = vbNo 
>     Cancel = True 
> End If 
>
> End Sub
> ```

<sup>1</sup> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865076%28v=office.15%29.aspx